# Is there any way modify dll's when it is being used by another process?

Tags: c#, windows, file, dll, msbuild

I am currently working in a application which uses code from the dll's for its execution. The problem, I am facing with this application is that it follows a sequence of steps for its execution. So if, I faced a error or bug in the 10th step, I have to kill the application, guess what bug it might be and make changes in the code, build the dll and copy it to the application and execute it from the first step.

This step is taking much more unwanted time for finding even a small error. I have tried to replace the dll's directly without killing the application but I am unable to do it as the windows won't allow for file change when it is being used by another process.

Much of my work is becoming unproductive because of this issue. I have tried several steps online but I am not getting expeted results from it.I have thought about saving all the objects used in the code until that step and use the same objects with the new dll's but I was not able to do that too.

I am open for any solutions to solve this issue.

Comment: I would concentrate on ensuring correctness early and fine-grained by writing unit tests.

Comment: it is not possible, once the dll is loaded into memory it cannot be replaced, until execution stops or complete